# Use pre-existing network without modify inbound ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I have configurated the next compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
  
x-aws-cluster: cluster
x-aws-vpc: vpc-A
x-aws-loadbalancer: balancerB

services:
    backend:
        image: backend:1.0
        build: 
            context: ./backend
            dockerfile: ./dockerfile
        command: >
            sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations && 
                 python manage.py migrate && 
                 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002"
        networks:
            - default
            - allowedips
        ports:
            - "8002:8002"
            

    frontend:
        tty: true
        image: frontend:1.0
        build:
            context: ./frontend
            dockerfile: ./dockerfile
        command: >
            sh -c "npm i --save-dev vue-loader-v16
                    npm install
                    npm run serve"
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        networks:
            - default
            - allowedips
        depends_on:
            - backend
networks:
    default:
        external: true
        name: sg-1
    allowedips:
        external: true
        name: sg-2
```

I thought it like:

- sg-1: Default security group
- sg-2: Allowed IPs access

If I run

```
docker compose up -d
```

it runs well without any problem and I can use the app.

My dude is that the process create

```
Allowedips8002Ingress
Allowedips8080Ingress
Default8002Ingress
Default8080Ingress
```

I don't want this, I will have a allowed IPs inbound rules in sg-2. How can I avoid this?

Comment: okey... maybe i didn't think it well but, if i use 'expose' instead of 'ports' is the solution. I will try it

Comment: Docker networks are completely different from AWS networks and security groups; Docker Compose can't manipulate AWS security groups at all.  I'd suggest there's rarely a reason to use `networks:` in the Compose file as you're showing and in almost all cases it's fine to rely on the `default` network that Compose provides for you.

Comment: `expose:` in a Compose file does almost nothing at all, and if you have it you can usually safely delete it.

Comment: I need to publish a app with ECS (this part works well) but the access to the app must be limited by allowed IPs. My idea was to publish the app with a public IP and limit access by security groups. Is it a good or a stupid idea?

Comment: I've always heard that IP ACLing is unreliable and easily circumvented.  Configuring it is not something you can do at the Docker level, nor is it the sort of programming question that's on-topic for Stack Overflow.  DevOps.SE or Server Fault might be better places to ask.